# Conectar una Base de Datos a Delphi 7

Tags: mysql, delphi

**¿Cómo puedo hacer una conexión de MySQL a Delphi 7?**

Probé utilizando un conector de 32 bits que ofrece la página oficial de MySQL(mysql-connector-odbc-noinstall-5.2.7-win32.zip).

Comment: Hola Matías, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Cuando dices que has probado utilizando un conector, no me queda claro que tipo de conector es ese, y que has intentado del lado de Delphi. Así es difícil responder puntualmente a tu pregunta, de acuerdo a las reglas del sitio. Sugiero que leas [ask] y completes tu pregunta, ya que hay muchas formas de conectar a MySQL desde Delphi.

Comment: A mí no e queda claro como estás tratando de usar el conector en tu código, recuerda tratar de poner un [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción para conectar a MySQL es utilizar los componentes ZeosLib.

Los puedes descargar desde [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) .

ZeosDBO es un conjunto de componentes creados por ZeosLib Development Group, de distribución gratuita y posibilitan la conectividad con distintas bases de datos: MySQL, PostgresSQL, etc.

Descargue el paquete desde el sitio de ZeosLib e instálelos en su sistema mediante los siguientes procedimientos:

```
1. Descomprima el archivo .zip dentro de la carpeta Archivos de programas\Borland\Source\Zeos
2. Copie la DLL correspondiente a su versión de MySQL que se encuentra en la carpeta Archivos de programas\Borland\Source\Zeos\lib\mysql a la carpeta WINNT\SYSTEM32 o WINDOWS\SYSTEM32
3. Agregue el directorio Zeos\packages\delphi7\build a la opción Library Path de Delphi
4. De la carpeta Zeos\packages\delphi7 compile ZCore.bpl, ZParseSql.bpl, ZPlain.bpl y ZDbc.bpl
5. Si los paquetes anteriores se compilan sin problemas, compile y luego instale ZComponent.bpl. En la IDE aparecerá una nueva paleta de componentes como en la siguiente figura:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Aquí un tutorial en YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WFMYFz68RQ)

Comment: entonces son opensource? Puedes poner el código mínimo para agregarlos?

Comment: edite mi respuesta, cualquier cosa comentame